# ZIP file in the wild with a 12 byte data descriptor, without a signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, zip, compression

According to the ZIP specification at https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

```
4.3.9  Data descriptor:

     crc-32                          4 bytes
     compressed size                 4 bytes
     uncompressed size               4 bytes
```

and

```
   4.3.9.3 Although not originally assigned a signature, the value 
   0x08074b50 has commonly been adopted as a signature value 
   for the data descriptor record.  Implementers SHOULD be 
   aware that ZIP files MAY be encountered with or without this 
   signature marking data descriptors and SHOULD account for
   either case when reading ZIP files to ensure compatibility.
```

how can I find (or make with a tool), a ZIP file with a data descriptor that does *not* have the `0x08074b50` signature?

I know I can just... write it myself byte-by-byte, but I'm making a (streaming) unZIPper, and want to test with real-world ZIP files.

Comment: Never seen one. I just searched my SSD and found many zip files with data descriptors, but none without signatures.

Comment: By the way, [sunzip](https://github.com/madler/sunzip).